# SQL-запрос: REPLACE и подстановочный знак %. Как сделать правильно?

Tags: html, mysql, sql, база-данных, веб-программирование

В базе данных MySQL 5.7 есть таблица `wp_posts`, в которой находится колонка `post_content`.
Нужно построить SQL запрос, чтобы во всех записях колонки `post_content` ссылки вида:

```
http://example.com/component/tags/tag/15-text.html
```

заменить на ссылки вида:

```
http://example.com/tag/text.html
```

То есть, нам нужно заменить все символы, которые находятся между '`com/`' и '`text`',
на '`tag/`', с учетом того, что цифра в ссылке может быть любой одно-, двух- или трехзначной (от 1 до 999).

Если бы в функции `REPLACE` можно было использовать подстановочный знак '`%`',
то запрос мог бы выглядеть примерно так:

```
 UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'component/tags/tag/%-', 'tag/');
```

К сожалению, так это не работает. Опыта работы с БД у меня нет, но как мне кажется, нужный запрос
можно создать с помощью `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, но сделать это самому не получилось.
Поэтому, был бы признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: REPLACE() выполняет только замену литералов. для замены по шаблону используйте REGEXP_REPLACE().